# Proof function is bilinear

Tags: linear-algebra

As far as I understand,  given a function f(x,y) if one wants to show that it is bilinear,
It is sufficient to show that f can be expressed in a form $f(x,y) = x^tAy$ as these forms are always bilinear.
Could one provide an example of a function f(x,y) that cannot be expressed in this form? I dont really understand why a matrix representation $M_B(f)$ doesnt work in a non bilinear case e.g. $f(x,y) \neq x^tM_B(f)y $

Comment: Well $f(x,y)= x^y$ is not bilinear and matrices cannot be used for bilinear maps in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Another example would be constant maps. Note that if we plug $x=0$, then $x^t A y=0$. Hence, $f(x,y)=1$ cannot represented that way.

Comment: The matrix's entries encode, literally, what the bilinear function does to pairs of standard basis vectors. Indeed, $f(e_i, e_j) = e_i^\top M e_j = (M)_{ij}$. When the function is bilinear, this is all the information you need; you can figure out $f(x, y)$ using linearity in each component. General functions of two variables are unconstrained by linearity, and free to do anything between these standard basis vectors. Knowing their values on any finite set of points will tells us nothing about the other values.

Comment: $f(x,y)=y^3 + \sin(xy)$.